# Efficiently return insertion point indices with fractional components using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, performance, numpy

I am looking to efficiently calculate the indices where elements should be inserted in an array to maintain order but *including* a fractional component signifying the "distance" between the two nearest points in the array.

It should be possible to get back the original value using the index and fraction. In practice, and the reason why performance is important, I'll need to do this for a large number of data points.

To demonstrate what I mean, I have come up with some working logic via `np.searchsorted` and some `if` statements, but have not been able to vectorise the logic with NumPy. I am also happy to see an efficient solution which utilises numba and has comparable or better performance versus NumPy. Or even a ready made solution in NumPy, Scipy, etc that I'm not aware of.

I have also included some benchmarking code below.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

datapoint = np.random.random() * np.random.choice([1, -1]) * 500  # -274.4067
line = np.linspace(-500, 500, 101)  # [-500, -490, ... , 0, ..., 490, 500] - an ordered array, may not be linspace

def get_position(line, point):
    position = np.searchsorted(line, point, side='right')
    size = line.shape[0]
    if position == 0:
        main = 0
        fraction = 0
    elif position == size:
        main = size-1
        fraction = 0
    else:
        main = position - 1
        fraction = (point - line[position-1]) / (line[position] - line[position-1])
    return main, fraction

idx, frac = get_position(line, datapoint)              # (22, 0.55932480363376269)
print(line[idx] + frac * (line[idx + 1] - line[idx]))  # -274.4067; test to see if you get back original value

def run_multiple(line, data):
    out = np.empty((data.shape[0], 3))
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        idx, frac = get_position(line, data[i])
        out[i, 0] = data[i]
        out[i, 1] = idx
        out[i, 2] = frac
    return out
```

**Benchmarking**

```
# Python 3.6.0, NumPy 1.11.3, Numba 0.30.1
# Note: Numba 0.30.1 does not support "side" argument of np.searchsorted; not able to upgrade

n = 10**5  # Actual n will be larger
res = run_multiple(line, np.random.random(n) * np.random.choice([1, -1], n) * 500)  # 901 ms per loop

# array([[ -4.22132874e+02,   7.00000000e+00,   7.86712571e-01],
#        [ -4.28972809e+02,   7.00000000e+00,   1.02719119e-01],
#        [  4.23625869e+02,   9.20000000e+01,   3.62586939e-01],
#        ..., 
#        [ -1.88627877e+02,   3.10000000e+01,   1.37212282e-01],
#        [  4.98162640e+01,   5.40000000e+01,   9.81626397e-01],
#        [  1.35777097e+02,   6.30000000e+01,   5.77709684e-01]])
```

Comment: Also, numba [does support](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/developer/autogen_numpy_listing.html#numpy.searchsorted) the `right` argument of `searchsorted` now.   Are you stuck using the old version?

Comment: @user3483203, Unfortunately, for now, yes, I added that as a code comment in the benchmarking section, should have highlighted it more.

Comment: Why not using the implementation from newer Numba version? It is in line 3347 https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/targets/arraymath.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some function isn't supported by Numba (or by the version you are using) it is always a good idea to have a look at [Numba source code](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/targets/arraymath.py) and see what is already there.
Quite often at least parts of a problem are already implemented.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

#almost copied from Numba source
#https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/targets/arraymath.py
"""Copyright (c) 2012, Anaconda, Inc.
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
met:

Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.

Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
"AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
(INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
"""
@nb.njit()
def searchsorted_right(a, v):
    n = len(a)
    if np.isnan(v):
        # Find the first nan (i.e. the last from the end of a,
        # since there shouldn't be many of them in practice)
        for i in range(n, 0, -1):
            if not np.isnan(a[i - 1]):
                return i
        return 0
    lo = 0
    hi = n
    while hi > lo:
        mid = (lo + hi) >> 1
        if a[mid]<= v:
            # mid is too low => go up
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            # mid is too high, or is a NaN => go down
            hi = mid
    return lo

@nb.njit()
def get_position(line, point):
    position = searchsorted_right(line, point)
    size = line.shape[0]
    if position == 0:
        main = 0
        fraction = 0
    elif position == size:
        main = size-1
        fraction = 0
    else:
        main = position - 1
        fraction = (point - line[position-1]) / (line[position] - line[position-1])
    return main, fraction

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def run_multiple(line, data):
    out = np.empty((data.shape[0], 3))
    for i in nb.prange(data.shape[0]):
        idx, frac = get_position(line, data[i])
        out[i, 0] = data[i]
        out[i, 1] = idx
        out[i, 2] = frac
    return out
```

**Timings**

```
n = 10**5
line = np.linspace(-500, 500, 101)
points = np.random.random(n) * np.random.choice([1, -1], n) * 500

%timeit run_multiple(line, points)
#1.08 ms ± 14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

#@user3483203
%timeit frac(line, points)
#8.65 ms ± 266 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

To vectorize this, I would mask out the edge cases, and worry about them at the end.  You only ever need to consider the `position == size` condition anyways, since the low condition is just zero in the respective columns, which already is satisfied by the `out` array.

```
def frac(line, points):
    pos = np.searchsorted(line, points, side='right')
    low = pos == 0
    high = pos == line.shape[0]
    m = ~(low | high)
    ii = points[m]
    jj = pos[m]
    frac = (ii - line[jj-1]) / (line[jj] - line[jj-1])
    out = np.zeros((points.shape[0], 3))
    out[:, 0] = points
    out[m, 1] = jj - 1
    out[m, 2] = frac
    out[high, 1] = line.shape[0] - 1
    return out
```

---

***Benchmark***

```
n = 10**5
line = np.linspace(-500, 500, 101)
points = np.random.random(n) * np.random.choice([1, -1], n) * 500

In [5]: %timeit run_multiple(line, points)
1.23 s ± 53.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [7]: %timeit frac(line, points)
13.4 ms ± 290 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [8]: np.allclose(frac(line, points), run_multiple(line, points))
Out[8]: True
```